# Unable to access remote repository for Go module import

Tags: git, go, gitlab

I need to be able to import Go modules from my company's private Gitlab repository, but there's something I'm very obviously not getting about how it works.

The module in question looks something like this at the top of my `go.mod` file:

```
module gitlab.domain.company.com/path/to/repository
```

Here's my go env:

```
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\E049839\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\E049839\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\E049839\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=*.company.com
set GONOSUMDB=*.company.com
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\E049839\go
set GOPRIVATE=*.company.com
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.19
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GOAMD64=v1
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=C:\N\the_program\go.mod
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\E049839\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build416370598=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

I use ssh exclusively to push and pull from the company's Gitlab, so I don't know why that would be my issue, but here's my `.gitconfig` anyway:

```
[url "ssh:/git@gitlab.domain.company.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://gitlab.domain.company.com/
[url "ssh:/git@gitlab.company.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://gitlab.company.com/
```

Any time I try to `go build` or `go get` for this project, I'm given this error:

```
go: gitlab.domain.company.com/path/to/lib: unrecognized import path "gitlab.domain.company.com/path/to/lib": https fetch: Get "https://gitlab.domain.company.com/path/to/lib?go-get=1": dial tcp xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxx: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Some info redacted obviously.

My version of Go is 1.19 running on Windows. I'm out of ideas trying to fool with this module, to the extent that I'm considering rewriting the entire application in a language with sensible version control.

Comment: Run `go get -x gitlab.domain.company.com/path/to/lib`. This will show you the `git` commands that go runs (e.g. `git remote add origin -- https://gitlab.domain.company.com/path/to/lib`). You can then run those commands manually to debug (perhaps after setting [`GIT_TRACE`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITTRACEcode). There are [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Remote_import_paths) covering how Go maps the import path to a repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had totally slipped my mind that my ssh was configured with a password. Now that I'm past that, it's working swimmingly. Thank you to everyone who contributed. I'm leaving this up as a suggestion to anyone experiencing the same issue in the future: if you have a password configured with ssh, you will have to account for it. In my case, I was able to just remove it, which is probably not best practice, but works.

Answer (score 1):

Your ssh url looks a little funky. My github one used to look like `ssh://`. That error means it is not using ssh, so it is not reading the config correctly.

Comment: I've edited my `git.config` several different ways, and it makes no difference. I'm still able to push and pull from the very same gitlab instance using this ssh configuration, but it somehow doesn't apply when go attempts to.

Answer (score 1):

There are known issues<sup>[[1]](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/30785) [[2]](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/36354)</sup> with retrieving go modules from gitlab projects, particularly those that reside within subgroups.

There's a few [workarounds](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/30785#note_622766081) described in that issue (one of which you are using) but this does not work in all circumstances like subgroups nested beyond `top-level-group/project`.

For self-hosted instances you can enable the [go proxy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/go_proxy/) which also eliminates the problem.  Or if you have your project directly under a top-level group, this will also avoid the problem.

In your case, however, this seems to be [additionally] a misconfiguration because the error is a networking issue (despite you being able to access these services normally):

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

This is a networking error not necessarily related to gitlab or go get...

Answer (score 0):

Try the same setting (with `ssh://...` instead of `ssh:/...`) in `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`.

I am not aware of a `git.config` file.